# Fast Order Statistic Tree in C# or a what DS is more efficient that SortedList providing the same functionality?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I need a Fast **Order Statistic Tree** in my C# code. The only data structure I know that has **IndexOf**() method and keeps items sorted is **SortedList**. Unfortunately, its insertion complexity is O(n) unlike **SortedDictionary** that is O(Lg n) but SortedDictionary does not have IndexOf().

The methods I need are just **Add**() and **IndexOf**()

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you write your own IndexOf() extension method for SortedDictionary? Of course it'll be terribly inefficient O(n)...just iterate all items

Comment: Please specify complexity of all operations (add, remove, search by value, search by index) - it will make it easier to find matching data structure.

Comment: Why do you need to know the index of an item in a sorted dictionary?  It's not an operation that really makes a whole lot of sense for that data structure, which of course is why it doesn't have an implementation of the method.  I'd say it's more likely you should just be re-working your code to not be using indexes when working with the collection.

Comment: @Adriano, the thing is that for implementing IndexOf() with O(lg n) complexity I need access to the underneath RBTree used by SortedDictionary which I don't know how to access to.

Comment: @Servy, it is a common need to know IndexOf() in a sorted collection and as you mentioned it is already implemented in SortedList (Kind of priority queue). My problem is that SortedList.Insert() is slow. The problem that I am trying to solve is number of shifts you need to do for sorting an array by Insertion Sort which requires an implementation of Order Statistic Tree.

Answer (score 1):

An [indexable skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist) has O(log n) insertion, removal, and `IndexOf`. Unfortunately, implementing skip list in C# involves some tradeoffs.

I haven't built an indexable skip list, but I did discuss building a regular skip list in two different articles:

- [The skip list data structure](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=875)
- [A more memory efficient skip list](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=876)

Modifying either of those to do the indexing shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a [nice implementation of Red-black tree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8287/Red-Black-Trees-in-C) and implemented [my own Order Statistic Tree](https://github.com/pbisadi/Algorithms/blob/master/DataStructures/SearchTree/OST.cs). It is a generic DS. 
As it does not have all general purpose properties of framework DSs it works 5 times faster for my specific problem.